# VueJs Avoid mutating a prop that is initialized on the created lifecycle hook

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to VueJs, i have a props property and at the created hook i get the property data.

But i am receiving this message at the console :

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. 
Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. 
Prop being mutated: "markets"
```

I declare markets at props section:

```
 props: {
      markets: Object           
    },
```

I get the property data at the created hook :

```
created() {

        Axios.get('/api')
          .then(response => {
            this.markets = response.data
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('There was an error:', error.response)
          }),
```

How can i adapt this situation to stop the warning messages ?

Comment: You should probably declare it as `data`, or you should modify the `markets` in the parent component.

Comment: Thank you @Terry! i declare into data and now the warning message is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in the [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow), this should be done as follows:

```
props: {
   markets: Object           
},
data: function () {
  return {
    innerMarkets: this.markets
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i see @Jota.Toledo is the case for this rule : The prop is used to pass in an initial value; the child component wants to use it as a local data property afterwards.

Comment: This can be dangerous, because the `markets` that is inherited from the parent is actually not updated. If you intend to ensure a single source of truth, you should avoid doing this data-remapping. Instead, either mutate the data in the parent component directly, or do not use `props` and declare the `market` as part of the component's `data` instead.

Comment: @Terry In the case that OPs intent was to _share_ the `markets` value between the parent and the child then sure, he would need to sync them through a different approach. But he did not mention anything like that. As it seems, his use case matched the first one described in the linked doc site; passing initial value from parent and then updating it locally, without parent sync.